# Perl Regex replace all domain except a particular in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string of domain like below:

```
$string = 'https://code.google.com && http://mycode.com/data && times.com && https://thehindu.com';
```

I want to replace all domains except `mycode.com` with `mycode.com/unknown`

So the output of above string after applying regex should be:

```
https://mycode.com/unknown && http://mycode.com/data && mycode.com/unknown && https://mycode.com/unknown
```

I have tried below regex, but it changes `http://mycode.com/data` also:

```
$string =~ s/(?<!mycode)[a-z\.]+?\.(com|org|net)/mycode\.com\/unknown/g;
```

How should i modify my regex to not match mycode.com

Comment: actually i am going to replace its with mycode.com/unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the matching part of the regex by that :

```
(http:\/\/)?(?!(mycode\.|ycode\.|code\.|ode\.|de\.|e\.))[a-z\.]+?\.(com|org|net)
```

Comment: gives error to me: Variable length lookbehind not implemented in rege

Comment: Oh, right, Perl does not support that.. I'll try something else, please check my answer again in a sec.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry, was coming up with better answer. Please try, @kailash19 . It works here.

Comment: @kailash19 Remember to accept an answer if it suits you. Hope you have a good day!

Answer (score 4):

```
$s =~ s{
   ( [a-z.]+\.(?:com|org|net) )
   (?![a-z.])
}{
   $1 eq "mycode.com" ? $1 : "mycode.com/unknown"
}xeg;
```

or

```
$s =~ s{
   (?<![a-z.])
   (?! mycode\.com (?![a-z.]) )
   ([a-z.]+\.(?:com|org|net) (?![a-z.])
}{mycode.com/unknown}xg;
```

Handles

- `mycoder.com`
- `mycode.combo.com`
- `mycode.combo`
- `notmycode.com`
- `foo.combo`

Comment: +1: It is a nice contribution! (although  it fails with some examples like `http://google.com/path`
`http://google.pt`
`http://v1.com`
`http://mycode.com/file.net`
`http://mycode.com/file.org/a.com_b.net`) -- that **are not really significant for the understanding of the main idea**

Comment: Excellent contribution! Thank you for checking every answer so thoroughly, Ikegami.

Comment: @JJoao, I get the expected answer from all of those??

Comment: for example: the first solution (before the "or") with the last example `http://mycode.com/file.org/a.com_b.net` wrote me `http://mycode.com/mycode.com/unknown/mycode.com/unknown_mycode.com/unknown`

Comment: That's what the OP asked for

Comment: @ikegami, sorry to insist. Do you really find reasonable to destroy the path when the domain is `mycode.com`?

Comment: @JJoao, Not destroyed, replaced. Like the OP asked.

Comment: @ikegami, I belive you are producing wrong answers for the example presented, but of course I will keep the upvote because I think it is a useful contribution. :)

Comment: @JJoao, I you think the OP meant something other than what he said, you can ask him for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You're really closed, instead of lookbehind, use lookahead:

```
my $string = 'https://code.google.com && http://mycode.com/data && times.com && https://thehindu.com';
$string =~ s~(?<![a-z.])(?!mycode)[a-z.]+\.(?:com|org|net)~mycode.com/unknown~g;
say $string;
```

**Output:**.

```
https://mycode.com/unknown && http://mycode.com/data && mycode.com/unknown && https://mycode.com/unknown
```

Comment: Handles `mycoder.com`, `mycode.meow.com` and `foo.combo` incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this

```
$string =~ s/https?:\/\/([^\/\s]+)/$match=$1;($match!~\/mycode.com\/)?'https:\/\/mycode.com\/unknown':$match/eg;
```

Comment: That doesn't even handle the example the OP gave.

Comment: Tip: If your pattern has a lot of `/`, it pays to use a different delimiter (e.g. `s{...//...}{...}` instead of `s/...\/\/.../.../`)

Answer (score -1):

(Ignoring url without `http://...` and using 3 non-scrolling lines)

```
my $s = 'https://code.google.com && ....' 

$s =~ s!//(?=mycode.com($|[^.\w]))!\cA!g;        # // -> CTR-A
$s =~ s!//(\S+)!//mycode.com/unknown!g;
$s =~ s!\cA!//!g;                                # CTR-A -> //
```

Basic idea:

- protect/mark/save the special cases
- substitute the general situations
- put-back the specials

Comment: Fails to handle `times.com` (in OP's example) and `mycode.combo.com`

Comment: Saying you fail to handle something isn't handling it, and what about `http://mycode.combo.com`

Comment: As already mentioned, because it doesn't even work for the code the OP provided.

Comment: @ikegami, As I said before and in the answer I am ignoring the "time.com" like examples. The other examples, I think I am dealing with them correctly . Thank you for telling me the origin of the -1

Comment: If you choose to post an solution that gives the wrong answer, don't be surprised if you get downvoted.